# Event doesn't fire on change, where is the error

Tags: jquery, image, onchange

I've this HTML markup:

```
<img id="image" alt="Eye Lights Liners" title="Eye Lights Liners" src="http://kg.devserver/image/cache/data/llipsplatsqpkgmn-228x228.jpg">

<select name="option[227]" id="option_select">
  <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
  <option data="http://kg.devserver/image/cache/no_image-50x50.jpg" value="19">Black Knight</option>
  <option data="http://kg.devserver/image/cache/no_image-50x50.jpg" value="18">Angel</option>
  <option data="http://kg.devserver/image/cache/no_image-50x50.jpg" value="17">Amorous</option>
  <option data="http://kg.devserver/image/cache/data/42llpkgmn-50x50.jpg" value="20">Vegas Volt</option>
</select>
```

First I don't know if I can, arbitrary, use "data" in  if is wrong please point me in the right direction. Then following with the problem I would like to change the img#image src with the value from data value in the select#option_select. For that I made this jQuery code:

```
$('#option_select').change(function(e){
    $('#image').attr('src', $(this).attr('data'));
});
```

but itsn't working. Why?

Comment: Couple of things
- I believe 'this' becomes the image object and not the option selected, so you might want to store the selection value and then changing. - You can use .val() to get the value of the selected element (dropdown).

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot set the Option Value property to the uri?

Comment: @rontornambe yes, I use option value later at DB level for store this value, the data-src only works for change dinamically the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data attributes are invalid, `data-arbitraryName`.

```
<option data-src="http://kg.devserver/image/cache/no_image-50x50.jpg" value="19">Black Knight</option>
```

```
$('#image').attr('src', $(':selected', this).data('src'));
```

Note that `this` refers to your select element not options, you can use `:selected` selector.

Comment: Hi, I try your solution and get this error `ReferenceError: src is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$('#image').attr('src', $(':selected', this).attr-src('data'));`

Comment: @ReynierPM Hi, sorry there was a typo, try it again.

Comment: Niceeeee!! man you rocks it works one last thing it's possible to change **anyname-50x50.jpg** to **anyname-228x228.jpg** on the fly? A little help?

Comment: @ReynierPM Yes, `$(':selected', this).data('src').replace(/50/g, '228')`;

Comment: something is wrong see the result `http://kg.devserver/image/cache/no_image-undefinedx228.jpg"` and of course the image doesn't exists